# Arduino robot with HC-06 not responding to Android input

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

While developing a robot basing on the Arduino MCU, everything worked fine. When I tried to add a remote control functionality with the HC-06 bluetooth module, there is no input. The android device connects fine with the HC-06 (the red light stops flashing). However, when I'm using the Bluestick app, it does not recognize any input.

I wrote a little piece of code to test the bluetooth module and it does not work either. The RX and TX pins on the module are connected to A0, and A1 on the Arduino while it is connected to the 3.3 volt input:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial BTSerial(A0, A1);

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  BTSerial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if(BTSerial.available()) {
    Serial.print("available");
    Serial.print(BTSerial.read());
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `SoftwareSerial` library is able to use the analog pins?
Could you try using the Digital pins and check if the problem persist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the easiest solution which comes in mind but...

The SoftwareSerial constructor prototype is

```
SoftwareSerial(rxPin, txPin, inverse_logic)
```

you connected RX pin to A0 and TX pin to A1. Consequently, you should call

```
SoftwareSerial BTSerial(A1, A0);
```

instead of

```
SoftwareSerial BTSerial(A0, A1);
```

Try this and let us know

Comment: You will learn that with serial communication half of the issues you have can be solved by just switching the two pins ;) Anyway glad it worked